# my phone number validation is not working properly

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

my phone number validation is not working properly.it is always showing error. I don't understand what is the problem. No error show in console. I use regex = / ^(?:+?88)?01[13-9]\d{8}$ / ;. for Bangladesh.

```
const number = document.getElementById('number');
    form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
         event.preventDefault();
         validate()
    })
    const sedData = (sRate, count) => {
         if (sRate === count) {
          alert("Registration successful");
          swal(`Welcome! ${username} registration successful`);
       }
     }
    const SuccessMsg = (usernameVal) => {
        let formCon = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control');
        var count = formCon.length - 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < formCon.length; i++) {
          if (formCon[i].className === "form-control success") {
          var sRate = 0 + I;
         sedData(usernameVal, sRate, count);
         } else {
           return false;
        }
     }
  }

   const validate = () => {
     const numberVal = number.value.trim();
            if (numberVal === "") {
              setErrorMsg(number, "number can not be blank");
            } else if (numberVal.match(regex)) {
               setSuccessMsg();
            } else {
               setErrorMsg(number, "Oops! your phone number is invalid");
         }
       }
    function setErrorMsg(input, errorMsgs) {
      const formControl = input.parentElement;
      const small = formControl.querySelector('small');
      formControl.className = "form-control error";
      small.innerText = errorMsgs;
  }
 function setSuccessMsg(input) {
   const formControl = input.parentElement;
   formControl.className = "form-control success";
 }
```

Comment: `/ ^(?:+?88)?01[13-9]\d{8}$ /` means it needs a space, *then* the start of the line, *then* the pattern, *then* the end of the line, *then* a space again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is the regex that you want `/^(?:\+?88)?01[13-9]\d{8}$/`

If something is wrong, please pass some examples of both right and wrong

Also, is it OK that you are using capital `I` in SuccessMsg in `var sRate = 0 + I;`?

Comment: If I give right number on first attempt nothing happened. Then I give  wrong number it gives error , error CSS and work properly. then  I  give the right number it gives error and error CSS

Comment: i am not using capital I in SuccessMsg in var sRate = 0 + I; I try capital I but not working

Comment: The style is not set to success because you don't pass the `input` parameter. It should be `setSuccessMsg(number);` in the `} else if ...` clause